# typescript generic array doesn't work typescript 3.9.7

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This works in typescript v4.1.3([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArmAlgRzgUwLIEMAOMC8MAPANIA0MAagHwAUiUaAthAFwwDaA1mgJ7vkYANywAbdpQC6HSQEoC1AFAwVMMGgDuMbDnqMWsgHQjR6CLVmLFoSCFFpDokAHNaAcnyev3n77-%203SxsIOwcnV2VVDkMYhBR0HVoONwBGACYANgBOAHY0twpUzNyUt0lDJlx6BU5ECkQ5WUlFIPAQ%200cXd38e3p7AoA)) but doesn't work in v3.9.7([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/MYewdgzgLgBArmAlgRzgUwLIEMAOMC8MAPANIA0MAagHwAUiUaAthAFwwDaA1mgJ7vkYANywAbdpQC6HSQEoC1AFAwVMMGgDuMbDnqMWsgHQjR6CLVmLFoSCFFpDokAHNaAcnyev3n77-%203SxsIOwcnV2VVDkMYhBR0HVoONwBGACYANgBOAHY0twpUzNyUt0lDJlx6BU5ECkQ5WUlFIPAQ%200cXd38e3p7AoA))

```
const uniqueMap = <K, V>(items: [key: K, val: V][]) =>
    new Map(items).values()
```

How to make this work. I am trying to make it generic so that I can use it for any kind of data.

My current work around

```
const uniqueMap = (items: any[]) => new Map(items).values()
```

Comment: You are using new feature from ts 4, that is why it is not working in ts 3.9. Have a look: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements. I would suggest not to use labels as your ts compiler doesn't support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuple labels are a TS 4.0 feature and not really all that useful, imo. Simplifying your code like this makes it compatible in all modern versions of TS:

```
const uniqueMap = <K, V>(items: [K, V][]) =>
    new Map(items).values()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/MYewdgzgLgBArmAlgRzgUwLIEMAOMC8MAPANIA0MAagHwAUiUaAthAFwwDa5VAuhzwEoC1AFAxxMMGgDuMbDnqMWAgHQA3LABt0EWgJEjQkEJrQrNIAOa0A5PnsPHT5y9c39RiCbMXrYiRwqQQgo6PK0HDYAjABMAGwAnADsMTYU0fHJUTY8Kky49MKciBSIggI8Ih7gXqbmVrauTc1N7kA)